# Geographic coordinates; Different latitude & longitude format?

Tags: r, geolocation, geospatial, geo

Does anyone know what format is the following coordinates in? Is it DMS?

```
Latitude    Longitude
N49-46.7    W086-56.4
N51-28.7    W000-27.7
N40-51.0    W074-03.6
N01-21.6    E103-59.4
```

How do I change it to decimal?

Comment: I suspect it is GPS http://boulter.com/gps/?c=N49-46.7++++W086-56.4#N49-46.7%20%20%20%20W086-56.4 but I would ask it at gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programminng.